# sudo takes a long time when connected to a VPN on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sudo, vpn, pam, ldap, domain

I am using Ubuntu 22.04. My machine is joined to my company's domain using Realm. I am not using Adsys. PAM is configured for Unix and SSS authentication.

While logged in as my domain user sudo is fast when I am in the office or remote, but when I log into the VPN it sometimes takes several minutes for sudo to prompt me for a password. The same is true for the gdm lock screen.

I `su`'ed to a local account which can sudo and used that to monitor /var/log/auth, (`sudo tail -f -n 100 /var/log/auth.log`) when the problem occurred.

I observed this:

```
Jul 27 08:23:53 nick-precision-7560 pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=1666422094)
Jul 27 08:23:53 nick-precision-7560 pkexec[10341]: nick: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/nick] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
Jul 27 08:25:46 nick-precision-7560 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1666422094 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/6 ruser=nick rhost=  user=nick
Jul 27 08:25:47 nick-precision-7560 sudo: pam_sss(sudo:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=1666422094 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/6 ruser=nick rhost= user=nick
Jul 27 08:25:47 nick-precision-7560 sudo:  nick : TTY=pts/6 ; PWD=/home/nick ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/whoami
Jul 27 08:25:47 nick-precision-7560 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=1666422094)
Jul 27 08:25:47 nick-precision-7560 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

So `pkexec` is the piece that seems to be taking so long.

There are a lot of similar questions like this around and the accepted solution has to do with the hosts file. I don't think this is the same issue since this only occurs when I connect to a VPN. I do suspect this is somehow related to name servers and LDAP though. FWIW here is my hosts file looks like:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   nick-precision-7560 nick-precision-7560.companydomain.mycompany.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I monitored `systemd-resolved` during the time this occured and didn't see anything in the logs there. Interestingly `resolvectl status` didn't change when I logged into the VPN, I thought it would have. However after logging into the VPN I saw that `/etc/resolve.conf` was updated and looks like:

```
#@VPNC_GENERATED@ -- this file is generated by vpnc
# and will be overwritten by vpnc
# as long as the above mark is intact
# This is /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
# Do not edit.
#
# This file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf. If you're looking at
# /etc/resolv.conf and seeing this text, you have followed the symlink.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
# through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
# different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

options edns0 trust-ad
nameserver 10.3.1.140
nameserver 10.3.1.43
search . companydomain.mycompany.com
```

I reach out to my IT department and they could see traffic from my IP hitting several of the domain controllers around the time of the incident and didn't see any of it getting rejected in the firewall logs.

I am not sure where to go next with trying to debug this issue. The issue isn't readily reproducible. It only occurs if I haven't logged in or used sudo in a long time while connected to the domain. But sometimes when I expect it to occur it doesn't, even times when I see from the auth logs unix authentication failed and had to use pam_sss for authentication.

*UPDATE:*
I ran Wireshark and monitored my TUN adapter. Eventually one of these sudo hangs occurred. I looked through the logs and saw a lot of DNS, LDAP, and SMB traffic. Looking through the journal I can see that Adsys is still running even though I am not using it for authentication and it's having some repetitive failures which generate a lot of network traffic and a lot of messages in the logs. I have uninstalled Adsys to see if that improves things. At the very least I think it should clean up the network traffic and logs to spot the issue.

At this point I know that my computer is resolving and talking to the correct domain controller and it is using the correct name servers.

Comment: You said your system is configured for SSS authentication.  Is your computer's sssd daemon asking the corporate domain controllers for permission when you invoke sudo?  Could this conversation be blocked when you activate the VPN?

Comment: From my experience it happens when you have issues resolving DNS entries. Can't say much without more information from your routes and VPN, but are you sure that OpenVPN has been able to update your DNS servers? Also, are them really reachable? Is your hostname resolvable? These are things I'd confirm...

Comment: @SottoVoce Yes, I suspect sssd is sometimes trying to authenticate with the domain controller. I do not think the conversation is getting blocked by something like a firewall because we weren't seeing blocked traffic in the firewall logs, but some sort of routing or host name resolution issue may be occurring.

Comment: @zip I'm not sure my DNS servers have been updated. resolve.conf has changed, but I am not seeing anything in the logs for resolved that makes me thing they've actually be updated. Any suggestions on where else I should look or what I should do to test this?

Comment: @Nick yes, I'm thinking of routing too.  Activating a VPN often changes the route table on the client, and that could be sending the sssd-->domain-controller packets through the wrong network interface when the VPN is up...

Comment: I confirmed via wireshark that my PC is talking to the correct domain controller via the VPN tunneling adapter. I do not see any obvious smoking guns in the LDAP exchanges though.

Comment: I think my next step may be to start monitoring what sssd specifically is printing to its logs. I added `debug_level=6` in my sssd.conf to increase its verbosity.

Comment: It's not clear if you need the AD integration in your system. If not, or rather just for testing, try  commenting the PAM entries related to domain services. Especially in the pam policy that applies to your pkexec binary. You should at the least be sure it IS the ad integration the culprit.

Comment: Just adding that this being intermittent is very weird. There may be something that changes your settings causing this after a while. The best strategy I can think is to remove or replace a setting at a time until you find one that stops it. Don't have many ideas here but I'm curious to as to whatever is causing this.

Comment: I do think it is AD related because I don't see this issue at all with a local account.

I was in the office this morning and I noticed that it took a little bit of time to get a password prompt when I entered a sudo command (~30s). I've got a wireshark log of that too that I can compare to my other log.

The journal for sssd hasn't been very verbose and hasn't given me any clues.